# JavaMail intermittently not reading emails from Microsoft Exchange using IMAP

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I have a Javamail program which runs as a Windows Service using Procrun. The main purpose of the program is to read the emails from the mailbox and do some processing with the emails. However once in a while it so happens that no mails are read from the mailbox even though the Java Program does not throws any error. It's not able to identify and read any emails in the mailbox unless restarted.

For reference I have pasted the code below which manages the connection. I have left out the business logic part of it

Comment: That's a lot of code. Do you have a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: [Folders need to be closed](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#close-boolean-) after you are done using them.

Comment: Is that really your password posted above?  Time to change it!

Comment: If closing the archive folder doesn't solve the problem, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) when it fails.  The moveMessages method is missing, but depending on what it does you may not even need to open the archive folder.  Also, you [don't need the socket factory properties](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).